# How can I see exactly what PHP output to the client?

Tags: php

I'm creating a PHP backend for an iPhone app.
I use PHP to generate xml for the client.  When there's a problem I'd like to see exactly what was sent to the client app, without having access to a user's device.

Instead of using `echo` to output to the client I've tried building all the output in a string and then as a last step using echo to output the string.  That way I can also save that output string to a file for debugging.  But when there are parse errors and such, the script generates a different output than what is saved in my $output string.

What low-level function can I use to save the exact output to the client, in a file on the server?

Comment: search for ob_start(), ob_get_contents() and ob_clean() or wait for some answer telling more about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it before script execution

```
ob_start(function($text){
    //log $text;
    return $text;
});
```